# Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -minerthreads

Tags: geth

I am getting this error when building a private Ethereum node:

```
flag provided but not defined: -minerthreads
```

This happens whenever I try to start the node?
by the way this is the main script for `startnode.cmd`:

```
geth --networkid 4224 --mine --minerthreads 1 --datadir "." --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password ./password.sec
```

Comment: Even if it's started from cmd.exe, the question is only about parameters of an external program and is not related to the `[batch]` or `[cmd]` tags

Answer (score 1):

Try `--miner.threads=1` instead. See geth command line options [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options)